# Can I set the record limit of Laravel's paginate method with user information?

Tags: laravel, sql-injection, laravel-pagination

I'm using the `paginate` method of the query builder and I would like to allow the user to choose the number of items per page.

```php
$paginate= Model::paginate($request->input('per_page'));
```

Doing this could I be opening a loophole for `SQL Injection` or is this value sanitized first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such methods must be protected. This is what models are for.

But you are right, it's better to be safe than sorry and verify your premises. This is especially true with popular frameworks, because sometimes the creators crave for simplicity above everything else, often forgetting even security.

But it seems that in this case, Laravel QueryBuilder [casts](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/e8b3ccdf7d0c71974d315a5616caf11d6abf1423/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php#L867) the `perPage` value to integer, making it immune to SQL injection:

```
protected function compileOffset(Builder $query, $offset)
{
    return 'offset '.(int) $offset;
}
```

Then I dug a bit into the history, and found that [the protection has been added almost a decade ago](https://github.com/illuminate/database/commit/459526d67c9b03fbdeba419262ee890959aad547), so you can be sure that with any supported version of Laravel this part is safe.

That said, validating user input is still a good idea. Even being protected from SQL injections, you don't want any unexpected behavior. I don't think `500000` or `-100` are good values whatsoever. If you can see that the data is not valid, it's a good strategy to bail off already, without waiting for some bizarre things to happen. So you may consider validating this input value just like any other input, like good programmers always do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a validator to make sure $request->input('per_page') is an integer or whatever validation you want.

documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation

Comment: This is not how SQL injection protection works.

Comment: @YourCommonSense what is wrong with this suggestion ? validating the input when using an advance and fairly secure framework like laravel is a good suggestion.

Comment: @N69S yes, it's a good *suggestion* but it doesn't nearly *answer* the question. And can be even dangerous, because SQL injection protection should be done at the query level, and never trusted to the validation level.

Comment: @N69S this was posted as an answer. A misleading answer. Hence the vote. Have a nice day.

Comment: @YourCommonSense and @N69S, as responsible for the question, I'll leave my opinion: I chose @YourCommonSense's answer because it is more detailed and within the scope of the question. As for @KarlMounguengui's answer, I don't think it's wrong, but a bit out of the scope of the question, and yes, I consider it as a form of protection against `SQL injection`, so I'll give it a vote as well.

Comment: The biggest problem with SQL injection is that people do not understand it. And instead of consistent approach they resort to random chaotic moves that inevitable would lead to injection

Comment: @YourCommonSense Could you please explain what you mean so I can learn ? Why the validation is not enough ?

Comment: @KarlMounguengui validation is just irrelevant to SQL injections. That's different matters. Protection from SQL injection is a matter on it's own. It must work regardless of any validation. This is an MVC application. The model can be called a dozen different methods. and with your validation you are only "protecting" one. Validation is optional and SQL inj prevention is obligatory. YOur validation only protects **numbers** but SQL injection prevention must protect any type of data

Comment: Ok. But in this case it was for number only right ? Is it possible to make an sql injection with this validation ? I just want ton make sure i understand

Comment: I really like this answer, @KarlMounguengui, because it encourages the use of validation. If OP were to validate first, OP would have a safer query even if Laravel were to not cast pages to an int. Without validation, the OP may rely on user providing pagination value, which could be 10K records and that could cause poor query performance. So, validating and choosing a reasonable pagination number is a suggestion I'd benefit from. Input validation is relevant to SQL Injection (https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html)